# "I'm sorry for all that I've done" or "I'm sorry for all what I've done"?

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure which is right:

1. I'm sorry for all that I've done.
2. I'm sorry for all what I've done.

Comment: ..........Use the first option............

Comment: Why? Could you explain it to me more clearly please?

Comment: I would reserve *what* for a question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*I'm sorry for all what I've done* is incorrect. *I'm sorry for all that I've done* is correct grammatically but requires the right context.

In terms of context, I might say *I'm sorry for all that I've done* if I were thinking about past actions I made that I regret. It is a large sweeping apology. However, I would not use the phrase in the context of *I'm sorry that I made a few blunders in the last twenty minutes*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way is it right to use"I was at home myself"or"I was at home by myself"

Comment: "I was at home myself" might mean that I am at home and other people were home as well, although I would put a comma between the word "home and word "myself". "I was at home by myself" means that I am at home alone.

Comment: Thanks! And if  you don't mind, I've got another question.

Comment: Everyone has some secret.

Comment: Or Everone has some secrets. Which is grammarly right?

Comment: The same question to"at some moment"or"at some moments.